# How to pause process in node js using spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

Is there any way, how to pause process in node js?

```
          const { spawn } = require('child_process');

          const process = spawn("run.cmd");

          process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
          });

          process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
          });

          process.on('close', (code) => {

          });
```

I want call somethink like this: `process.pause()`, `process.continue()`.

Or some system call using cmd?

I am using windows.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the process PID and use linux command to pause/resume process by PID.
You can change your code to `process = spawn(cmd & echo $! > txt)`.
It would save your cmd process PID to txt, and then you can use `fs` to read the PID.

Now you have PID, run `exec()` to pause process `kill -STOP <PID>` or resume stopped cmd `kill -CONT <PID>`.
These two are unix command, should work fine.

Comment: Simpler, you can call `process.kill('SIGSTOP')` to pause the process and and `process.kill('SIGCONT')` to resume it.

Comment: @PeterBurns you would think so. It works on Mac. But on Windows: `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL]: Unknown signal: SIGCONT`

Answer (score 2):

I specifically made a library to pause/resume processes from Node.js on Windows, [ntsuspend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntsuspend).

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ntsuspend = require('ntsuspend');
const process = spawn("run.cmd");
ntsuspend.suspend(process.pid);
ntsuspend.resume(process.pid);
```

If you're using Linux or MacOS

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ntsuspend = require('ntsuspend');
const process = spawn("run.cmd");
process.kill('SIGSTOP');
process.kill('SIGCONT');
```

Comment: Use `process.platform === "win32"` to switch conditionally between these two approaches.

Answer (score -1):

Send it a signal: [read this](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal)

But what signal? [read this](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events)

Answer (score -2):

Just use the readline package, you can basically use the functions easily

To pause the process

`rl.pause()`

To resume the process

`rl.resume()`

If you want more information you can check out these two places

[Resume - node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_resume)

[Pause - node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_pause)